# get number according to preference

Tags: function, pyspark

I am looking to build a logic, Not sure how to. I need a function which does below task. 
I would like to get number according to preference. Say I have preference as
`1, 3, 2013, 154, 147`. Which means, 1 has highest preference, then 3 and then 2013 and so on.

If I have some thing as, `a = "1,3,2,14"` then function should should return me 1. 
if `a = "151, 152, 2013"` then fn(a) = 2013 
if `a = "3, 147, 151"` then fn(a)= 3 
if `a = "9999, 154, 8777, 45=3"` then fn(a)= 154

Can some one help me how to get the function? I'm looking to implement in pyspark.

Comment: What have you tried? Generally we like to help, not do the work for you.

Comment: Here I tried to explain the logic on a paper, hope it clear https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnDha.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am able to come up with logic to solve. I am going to run this on millions of records, If there is a scope to optimise it, please let me know.

```
precedence=[1, 3, 2013, 154, 147]
reverse_order=precedence[::-1]
def fn(a):
   temp = a.split(",")
   test = []
   for i in temp:
       if (i.find('=')!=-1):
           i = i.split('=')[0]
       if int(i) in reverse_order:
           test.append(reverse_order.index(int(i)))
        else:
            test.append(-1)
    if max(test)!=-1:
        return reverse_order[max(test)]
    return None
```